# Replace a for loop with apply family function on a xts

Tags: r, xts

Hi my xts structure is  :

```
head(sym)

                     BidSize  Bid  Ask    AskSize Quantity Mid
   2006-01-04 09:01:00    3771 181000 182000    5783    15625 181500
   2006-01-04 09:02:00    3952 181000 182000    5659      180 181500
   2006-01-04 09:03:00    3556 181000 182000    5943     1059 181500
   2006-01-04 09:04:00    3747 181000 182000    6133      261 181500
   2006-01-04 09:05:00    3957 181000 182000    6077      101 181500
   2006-01-04 09:06:00    3898 181000 182000    6511      311 181500
```

I have a function `getTickSize(x,date)` which is designed for x as a single numeric (not an array).

I would like if possible to replace the following for loop by a "smart" call to the apply family of functions

```
for (i in 1:nrow(sym[1:10])){
    sym$TS[i] <- getTickSize(sym$Mid[i],index(sym)[i])
  }
```

Any pointer ? all my attempts were met with the following warnings:

```
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: I would recommend you re-write your `getTickSize` function to operate on arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion any link or pointer to "vectorising" a function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case, `mapply` is the easiest solution:

```
sym$TS<-mapply(getTickSize, sym$Mid, index(sym))
```

Note: the `*apply` family of functions is not always better than a simple loop (most of the myth around that dates way back to early version of S).

But I admit it looks a lot sexier.

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. Also as expected no performance gains but sexier code .